# asp.net MVC controller - What should controller return if user is unauthorized?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

So I have this code inside the controller of my MVC for a page

```
[HttpGet, Route]
[Authorize(nameof(Access))]
public async Task<ActionResult> ListStuff()
{
      var canRead = HasAccess()

      if(!canRead)
      {
          throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
       }
}
```

I'm using C# attributes for security validation and what I want is if the attribute with the 'HasAccess()' function returns false then the page show show an 'unauthorized' error, as you guys can see I tried throwing an HttpResponseException, I'm pretty sure this isn't the proper way to do it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You send a GET http request to your running service, eg:http://localhost:8080/Myservice.svc/$metadata. I've used postman in the past to help with sending http requests. 
[Link to free postman](https://www.getpostman.com/)